# How to upload form contents with a file to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, file-upload

This is my code,i have also tried strongly typed view but i it does not create an upload field

```
   #Model
   namespace master_layout.Models

   {
    [Table("Candidates")]
    public class Candidate
    {

    [Key]

            public int CandidateID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public string EmailID{get;set;}
    public long ContactNumber{get;set;}
    public long AlternateContactNumber{get;set;}
    public int RecruitmentStatusID{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn{get;set;}
    public DateTime LastUpdatedOn{get;set;}
    public byte[] Resume { get; set; }
}
public class CandidateContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }

}
```

The following is my controller code

```
 Controller:

namespace proedit1.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    CandidateContext db = new CandidateContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View(db.Candidates.ToList());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Candidate candidate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Candidates.Add(candidate);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(candidate);
    }
}
}


View:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Newcandidate", "CandidatesController", FormMethod.Post, new {      EncType="multipart/form-data"}))
{
<table class="navbar-form">

<tr>
<th>First Name<input type="text" placeholder="Your First  Name" class="margin"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Last  Name<input type="text" placeholder="Your  Last Name"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Date of Birth&nbsp;<input type="date" name="db" /></th>

</tr>
<tr>
 <th>E-Mail ID<input  type="email" placeholder="abc@yourserviceprovider.com" /></th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Contact No<input type="tel" placeholder="04426506555    or 98414981414" min="8" maxlength="10"/></th>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Alternate No&nbsp;<input type="tel" placeholder="04426506555 or 98414981414" min="8" maxlength="10"/></th>
  <tr>
  <th>Created On&nbsp;<input type="date" /></th>

  <tr>
  <th>Updated On&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" /></th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <th> <input type="file" placeholder="your resume in ms.word format" accept="application/msword" name="NamebtnUpload"/>    
  </th></tr>
  </table>

  <div class="row">

 <div class="span4">

    <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="UPLOAD" name="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" class="btn-warning"    name="Reset" />    

</div>
</div>
}
```

I am a newbie in MVC pls provide me with the correct code to upload details to my database

Comment: *sidenote:* never use `&nbsp;` to align your HTML. Use CSS instead.

Comment: _sidenote #2:_ you've also added `&nbsp;` to the `name` attribute of your `submit` and `reset` buttons but the name values aren't for display. [I don't think this causes your problem though.]

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which are you looking for:

[MVC 4 Razor File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)

Create new view model for your 'view'. **[Don't use entity model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970763/asp-net-mvc-using-ef-entities-as-viewmodels)**, please.