# Mapping from and to view models using methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Suppose I have a class `Person`.

###### Model: *`Person.cs`*:

```
class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    public string Name { get; set; }
  
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a view model that contains two conversion methods:

- A `ToPerson()` to map to `Person`
- A static `FromPerson()` that constructs a `PersonViewModel` from `Person`.

###### View Model: *`PersonViewModel.cs`*

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Email, Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public Person ToPerson(Department department) => new()
    {
        Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name, Email = this.address, Department = department
    };

    public static PersonViewModel FromPerson(Person p) => new()
    {
       Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Email = p.Email, DepartmentId = p.Department.Id
    };
}
```

This enables me to write code like this in the controller:

###### Controller: *`PersonsController.cs`*

```
public class PersonsController : Controller 
{

    public IActionResult Create(PersonViewModel pvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           Department dept = departmentService.Get(pvm.DepartmentId);
           Person person = pvm.ToPerson(dept);
           personService.Add(person);
           return View(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(pvm);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id) 
        => personService.Get(id) is not null and var person 
        ? View(PersonViewModel.FromPerson(person)) 
        : NotFound();
}
```

I have come across [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). However, I feel having methods like this gives me more flexibility over the mapping operation like handling custom cases where a one-to-one mapping is not relevant while also tidying up controller boilerplate. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961737/11455105) answer where it is mentioned how AutoMapper may not always be well-suited for every use case.)

I know the question "*Should I do this?*" will be opinion-based. My question is:

"*Are there any side-effects or cons of doing it this way? Does it violate any design principles or is there anything against having logic in a view model? And are there better ways to tidy up mapping operations in controller actions?*"

Comment: I've been using "your" way in projects before. It is testable, and I can't see any problems doing this.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249475/trying-to-come-up-with-a-mapping-convention-for-c-objects

Comment: I've already tried this in one of my projects and everything worked well. The only cons of this might be when you have many model (entity) classes with many properties. In that case, writing many mapper methods would be tedious.