# Is there a conceptual difference between DTO (Data Transfer Object) and Data Object?

Tags: c#, database, naming-conventions, dto

In a project I inherited, on many occasions, there are classes named as `XyzDataObject`. Although called **DataObject**, they mostly look to me like what I usually refer to as a [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (**DTO**). They have some specialties to them however:

- Used in a an area, where only a subset of the domain data is used (good)
- Consist mainly of standard typed properties (fine)
- Super-minimal logic for instantiation (ok)
- Mapping functions from and to the Domain Objects (oops?)

Now it is my understanding from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678217/best-practices-for-mapping-dto-to-domain-object), that these mapping functions should be separate.

**Question**:

- **Is the mapping feature the reason these objects might be called "Data Objects" instead of Data  Transfer Objects?**

Or:

- Is this just a naming issue
  and they should be called DTO's anyway?
- Should the be named
  something else altoghether because of their mapping capabilities?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this boils down to a subjective naming issue. However, I would argue that a DTO should contain no logic whatsoever, including constructors. I suppose it depends on whether we're talking about a public API or a back-office system and what conventions your team have used in the past.

Comment: IMHO it's a design flaw, since DTOs should not have mapping capabilities themselves and Mappers should not be part of the entity they map. Mistakingly calling the classes you described "DataObjects" only creates confusion, as they simply appear to be a lazy blending of DTOs and Mappers.